# Is $\{a + bi: a, b \in \mathbb{F}_3\}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is $P = \{a + bi: a, b \in \mathbb{F}_3\}$ a field?  This is the question I am having.

First, I list the elements in $\mathbb{F}_3$, which consists of $\overline{0}$, $\overline{1}$ and $\overline{2}$ modulus 3.  Then, I form the quick idea whether that set is a field or not.

Suppose that $P$ is a field.

We need to show that $(P, +)$ is an abelian group.  Clearly, the addition of any elements, belonging to $(P, +)$, is always associative and also commutative.  The identity element is $\overline{0} \in (P, +)$.  The additive inverse of the element, say $a + bi \in (P,+)$ is $-a - bi$.  Realize that $-a$ and $-b$ modulo 3 are congruent to some elements in $\mathbb{F}_3$, which implies that $-a - bi \in (P, +)$.  So elements in $(P,+)$ have their additive inverses, in which $c_0 + (-c_0) \equiv 0$ for any $c_0$ in the form $\{a + bi : a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3\}$.

We then need to prove that $(P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$ is also an abelian group.  The product of the elements is also commutative and associative.  $\overline{1} = 1 + 0i$ is the identity element belonging to $(P \backslash \{\overline{0}\},\times)$.  Next, we need to show that each element in $(P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$ has the multiplicative inverse.  That is: If $p \in (P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$, then $p^{-1} \in (P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$ also.  If this happens, then this means that the product of nonzero elements $pp^{-1} = 1$, where $p$ and $p^{-1}$ are in the form $a + bi$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3$.  Observe that if $a + bi$ has its multiplicative inverse in $(P \backslash \{0\}, \times)$, then the multiplicative inverse is

$$\dfrac{1}{a + bi} \cdot \dfrac{a - bi}{a - bi} = \dfrac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2} = \dfrac{a}{a^2 + b^2} - \dfrac{b}{a^2 + b^2}i$$

where $a, b, a^2 + b^2 \text{ ($a^2 + b^2$ being nonzero)} \in \mathbb{F}_3$, and $a$ and $b$ are both not $\overline{0}$}

If we check the inverse of each element $a + bi \in (P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$, then each element has its multiplicative inverse.  This means that $a^2 + b^2$ is never $\overline{0}$.    Thus, $(P \backslash \{\overline{0}\}, \times)$ is an abelian group.

Clearly, $a(b + c) = ab + ac$ holds for any $a,b,c \in P$ since multiplication and addition are inherited from $(P, +)$ and $(P, \times)$.

Thus, $P$ is a field.

Any advices or comments?

Comment: We need to decide what $i$ might mean in this context. It is an object whose square is $-1$. Then if we define additon, multiplication of objects of type $a+bi$ in the natural way, we get something isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: It looks good up until distributivity.  Multiplication is only partly inherited from $(P,\times)$, so in a direct proof like yours you should work out this messy calculation for general $a,b,c$.

Comment: @vadim123 How would I show that distributivity holds?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, $i$ is really a complex unit in case to avoid confusion.

Comment: @NasuSama, $a=a_1+a_2i, b=b_1+b_2i, c=c_1+c_2i$, etc.

Comment: @vadim123 That is really messy...  However, it's the right way to go for!  Thanks vadim!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there's a far quicker way of doing this. Consider $F_{3}[x]$, the ring of polynomials over $F_{3}$. Notice that $x^{2}+1$ has no roots in $F_{3}$ and therefore, since its degree is 2, it is irreducible in $F_{3}[x]$. It is quite easy to show that this implies that $A:=F_{3}[x] /(x^{2}+1)$ is a field (you can do this by hands, finding an explicit inverse for each non zero element of that quotient, or arguing about maximality of ($x^{2}+1$)), where $(x^{2}+1)$ is the ideal generated by $x^{2}+1$ in $F_{3}[x]$. Now it should not be difficult to show that the linear map $A\longrightarrow P$ which sends $[a]$ to $a$ for $a\in F_{3}$ and $[x]$ to $i$ is an isomorphism (of rings). Since $A$ is a field, you get by this that also $P$ is such.